# LinkedIn - Cannot create access token, Responded with "This application is not allowed to create application tokens". #linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api, access-token

When trying to generate an access token in LinkedIn with my client id and silent secret I was responded with a message in JSON format saying:

> This application is not allowed to create application tokens

I use v2 OAuth. App yet to be verified.

The [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow) says that the access can only be enabled by LinkedIn itself and I couldn't find any documents that could tell me how to do that for now.
Kindly help me to generate the access token. #linkedin

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I just ran into this problem. Has anyone found a solution to this problem? It seems illogical that LinkedIn will make it so difficult for developers to use its API products.